# SharePoint pages reverting to old version automatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, version-history

The platform is SharePoint 2010. There have been a few cases where a page has been updated (a public facing page) to the next major version. At some point, the page, without any user interaction, reverts back to the previous version of the page. Typically the 'modified by' will state 'System Account'.

Is there a reason this is happening (besides someone deliberately doing it?

Comment: Seems like some workflow, timer job or possibly scheduled task? Any custom functionality like that in your environment?

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but there is no custom functionality that is connected to workflows/timers in anyways.